# How are zeros of a global analytic function defined? Are they isolated?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, reference-request, definition

According to Wikipedia,

An analytic function in an open set U is called a function element.

A global analytic function is a family f of function elements such that, for any (f,U) and (g,V) belonging to f, there is a chain of analytic continuations in f beginning at (f,U) and finishing at (g,V).

In this regard, I have the following questions:

1. What is meant by saying that a global analytic function vanishes on an open set in the complex plane?
2. If the above question makes sense, then does it imply that the global analytic function is identically zero?

Some references for the above would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what context have you heard/read *"a global analytic function vanishes on an open set in the complex plane"*? Please [edit] the question to include the details.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, @Rama; I'm sorry: it was wrong due to a technicality. Please [edit] your question to include the definition of a global analytic function to avoid such a confusion in future.

Comment: @Shaun : No problem. Many thanks for your immediate and kind response.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd like to apologise to @EricWofsey, too.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question, @Rama. However, it'd help to have a link to the specific Wikipedia article you are referring to. Type `[text](link)` to have a hyperlink with URL "link" and text "text".

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: An open subset of what? $\Bbb C$?